# Errors when activating API Gateway’s cache on AWS: no CORS headers returned from CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

We have a set of different APIs created by serverless (>= 1.18). They work nicely (with CORS) in production since months. Now we need to [activate the API Gateway's cache](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) but after that the API gives errors. Specifically I see this in browsers' Javascript console:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

When we press the "Flush cache" button in the API Gateway console, the first call to the API works (it doesn't go through the CloudFront cache), but as soon as the resource gets cached again, we immediately get the mentioned error again.

In summary, it seems that when activating the API Gateway cache, responses coming from CloudFront's cache "lose" the CORS headers.

For the moment we have disabled all API Gateway caches and everything is working back to normal, but this is going to create performance issues on the backend as usage of the API is increasing.

Has anybody else experienced this behavior or are we missing any configuration on serverless side? Is there any workaround?

**Serverless Framework Version**: 1.21.1

Comment: I couldn't replicate this issue.  Are you using your `serverless.yml` to configure caching, or are you doing it in the AWS console?  Updating the question with your `yml` might provide us with a clue.

Comment: Thaks Mike. Caching was added using the AWS console, if I well remember at the start of this project the option was not available in `serverless.yml`. I'm now trying to modify it and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @MikePatrick I was browsing the serverless documentation but still can't find a way to enable API Gateway caching within the`serverless.yml` file, could you please point me toward some documentation?

Comment: I also used the AWS console; I was just checking to see if we were performing the same steps.  I have also not managed to enable caching with `serverless.yml`, but [posts like this](http://theburningmonk.com/2016/04/serverless-enable-caching-on-query-string-parameters-in-api-gateway/) give me hope that it *might* be possible.  One possible workaround would be to try [using CloudFront for caching](https://github.com/Droplr/serverless-api-cloudfront) instead of API Gateway.

Comment: Sorry about the misplaced suggestion to use CloudFront; I see you're using both.  I was under the impression that [AWS creates an "internal" CloudFront distribution for your API Gateway resources.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=195290).  Have you created your own CloudFront distribution, and placed it in front of API Gateway?  If so, what's the use case for that (i.e. why both)?